# Composing and comparing a date in Java

Tags: java, android, date

I used this to create a date and put it into a database:

```
String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
```

I want to build a date with a similar format to the one above and compare it with `currentDateTimeString`.

I have 3 integers. How do I do that (int year, int month, int day)?

UPDATE:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

         cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
         cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
         cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);

         Date result = cal.getTime();
         String currentDateTimeString2 = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(result);
```

I do here something wrong..both arent equal:
currentDateTimeString2==currentDateTimeString //false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.DATE, date);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month-1);//it starts from 0
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
Date result = cal.getTime();
```

> I do here something wrong..both arent equal: currentDateTimeString2==currentDateTimeString //false

String are object, it can't be compared with `==` use `equals()` method

Comment: what i am trying to point out is when i get the currentDateTimeString2 to compare to what i have in teh database .. it says that there is no such date...i.e. currentDateTimeString2.equals(currentDateTimeString)...false

Comment: how do i debug with breakpoints in eclipse while using android?

Comment: can you tell me the content of both `String` ?

Comment: I don't see `month-1` taken care as I mentioned in my code. also you can just print the date its not an issue to debug

Comment: Toast.makeText(this, "Day: "+day+", Month: "+month+", Year: "+year,1000);..that refuses to appear

Comment: The day is set to 0 for some reason

Comment: It should be `DATE` not the `DAY_OF_MONTH`

Comment: No `month-1`, january is 0 for us its 1 , so -1

Comment: i have a problem with month now..it shows me that it is set to 7

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2356/discussion-between-jigar-joshi-and-dmitry-makovetskiyd)

Answer (score 1):

Dates are represented in milliseconds. new Date returns the current date, and by date it means year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond.

Comparison can be made via Date.isAfter.

Don't use Strings to compare Dates. Don't use == to compare Objects.